# ¿Cómo usar if y when en CheckBoxes?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, checkbox

Por ahora estoy utilizando if pero estoy segura que se puede resolver de mejor manera con when. Es un filtro que te indica el tipo de ambulancia que necesitas de acuerdo a tu situacion. Por esta razon se toman como niveles; una ambulancia basica puede atender un caso de asfixia y una embarazada, la ambulancia de urgencias avanzadas puede antender un infarto, pero tambien las dos situaciones anteriores,la ambulancia de cuidados intensivos puede atender una sobredosis, pero tambien las tres situaciones anteriores y asi sucesivamente..

```
private lateinit var binding: ActivityMain2Binding

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityMain2Binding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)
binding.btnAceptar.setOnClickListener {
    binding.apply {
        btnAceptar.setOnClickListener {
            if (ckbxAsfixia.isChecked == true || ckbxEmabrazada.isChecked == true || ckbxAsfixia.isChecked == true && ckbxEmabrazada.isChecked == true) {
                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity2, "Una ambulancia de urgencias básicas va en camino", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
            if (ckbxInfarto.isChecked == true || ckbxInfarto.isChecked == true && ckbxAsfixia.isChecked == true || ckbxInfarto.isChecked == true && ckbxEmabrazada.isChecked == true || ckbxInfarto.isChecked == true && ckbxAsfixia.isChecked == true && ckbxEmabrazada.isChecked == true ){
                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity2,"Una ambulancia de urgencias avanzadas va en camino",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
            if (ckbxSobredosis.isChecked == true){
                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity2, "Una ambulancia de cuidados intensivos va en camino", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
            if (ckbxMontana.isChecked == true){
                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity2, "Una helicoptero ambulancia va en camino", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
            if (ckbxAsfixia.isChecked == false && ckbxInfarto.isChecked == false && ckbxSobredosis.isChecked == false && ckbxMontana.isChecked == false && ckbxEmabrazada.isChecked == false) {
                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity2, "No has seleccionado ninguna opcion", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿cómo puedo implementar el when mezclado con el if?

Comment: Creo que aquí el principal problema para utilizar ```when``` es que según las reglas que indicaste se estaría mostrando más de un Toast para todos los tipos de ambulancia que no sean ambulancia básica, por ende esta condicional no sería la más adecuada para tu problema, ya que esta se adapta mejor para reemplazar multiples condicionales ```if``` - ```else``` que forman parte de un mismo bloque de código Puedes leer mas acerca de esto en la documentación de Kotlin -> [https://kotlinlang.org/docs/control-flow.html#when-expression](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/control-flow.html#when-expression)

Comment: Creo que en este caso, como tienes varias validaciones en algunos if, esta serìa una soluciòn adecuada, no creo que when sea una opciòn.

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo porque tienes un setOnClickListener dentro de otro setOnClickListener de la misma referencia, solo deja el que esta dentro del apply para que no escribas el binding antes de cada llamada.

Con respecto a si puedes usar when puedes usarlo de la siguiente manera, pero la verdad no hay diferencia con lo que ya tienes escrito, solo cambia la forma en la que estamos escribiendo la estructura de condiciones

```
val first: Boolean = true
val second: Boolean = true
val third: Boolean = false
val fourth: Boolean = false
val fifth: Boolean = false

when {
    first == true && second == true -> println("Caso 1")
    second == true && second == true -> println("Caso 2")
    third == true && second == true -> println("Caso 3")
    fourth == true && second == true -> println("Caso 4")
    fifth == true && second == true -> println("Caso 5")
    else -> println("Excepcion o caso faltante")
}
```

En este caso a pesar de que la primera y segunda condiciones son verdaderas solo imprimira la primera, que es la que se cumple primero.